# Аппроксимация кривой (сглаживание шума и пиков в числовом ряду)

Tags: математика, javascript

Здравствуйте!

Есть одномерный массив (размерностью в несколько тысяч элементов) вещественных числе. Если построить график по этим значениям, то видно что есть некоторая флюктуация (разброс) значений (с немногочисленными резкими пиками).

Пример (для наглядности, интервалы замеров равномерны):

- Показания температуры
- Уровень освещенности
- Заряд батареи
- Уровня жидкости
- и т.д.

исх.   10  12  15 40 17 16 12 10 22 12 14 15 14 10 12
сглаж.~ 10  13 15 16 16 14 12 16 14 13 14 14 13 11 12

Нужно не увеличивая число точек сгладить показания:
[image]
(примерный набросок: "сглаженная линия" - показания без резких скачков)

Понятное дело, что для этого нужна аппроксимация данных, но я уже несколько дней затрудняюсь привести найденный алгоритм аппроксимации кривой Безье к требуемому виду:

```
p1 = f(t) = p0 * (1-t)^2 + 2 * p2 * t * (1 - t) + p1 * t^2;
```

где, p1 сглаживаемое промежуточное значение между двумя своими соседями, t=0.5 (по идеи именно при 0.5 должна браться именно промежуточное значение).

Потом Нашел алгоритм [здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/post/130873/), а сам он выложен [тут](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25237/Bezier-Curves-Made-Simple).
Но данный алгоритм не подходит потому что работаем максимум на 32 точках, да и с факториалами он слишком долго на JS будет выполняться, если вообще будет. А записать алгоритм без факториалов (это вроде возможно, если верить [формулам из Википедии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%8C%D0%B5)) у меня не получается.

Ещё можно использовать приведенную мной формулу и пройтись ею по ряду, но не думаю что это хорошая идея... Если бы можно было использовать за раз больше 32 точек (хотя бы 100), то дело было бы веселее. Но я просто не знаю как это записать формулой по которой уже писать алгоритм...

Кто-нибудь знает как в числовом ряду сгладит "шум" и "пики" ?
Бьюсь уже не один день но что-то получается определиться с алгоритмом.
Я в математике не очень, поэтому не могу продраться через теорию к формуле...
Надеюсь кто-нибудь мне с этим поможет ?

Пробовал использовать "скользящее среднее" (по совету @lampa), но данные сильно искажаются. Вот код (вроде не накосячил, но кто его знает):

```
a=[40,40,40,40,37,40,36,39,36,39,34,39,35,38,33,37,35,34,36,35,34,33,33,33,32,33,32,33,32,33,31,32,29,31,29,31,28,33,27,30,25,29,24,28,28];
for (var i=n, l=a.length; i<l; i++) {
 s=0; for (var j=i, m=i-n; j>=m; j--) s += a[j];
 r[i] = s/n
}
```

Но в результате все равно остановился на исходном варианте - сглаживании Безье (квадратичной кривой):

```
for (var j=0, m=4; j<m; j++)
 for (var i=1, l=a.length-1; i<l; i++)
  a[i] = 0.5*(0.5*(a[i-1]+a[i+1])+a[i]);
```

4-ри прохода дают удовлетворительный результат.

PS Если не будет варианта получше, то останусь на этом варианте.

Comment: про кривые Безье всё-же предельно понятно:

![](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a4/B%C3%A9zier_4_big.gif)

(считайте координату вершины треугольника)

Comment: Конечно оффтоп, но при сглаживание изменением исходных данных, вы теряете истинность результата, не знаю где подобное может понадобиться, лишь для обмана, того же начальства, что в работе с оборудыванием ведет к неисправностям.

Comment: @avengerweb написано же, чтобы убирать шумы.

Comment: Да по сглаживанию на основе кривой Безье (при коэффициенте t=0.5 и ряда из значений полученных через равные промежутки времени) все понятно.  
Алгоритм вполне справляется с небольшим шумом (при циклическом проходе приведенной [кубической формулой]), но высокие пики (резкие кратковременные скачки показателя в 1-3 "точках" ряда) сглаживаются недостаточно...



  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Кривая_Безье#.D0.9A.D1.83.D0.B1.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.B5.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D0.BA.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.B2.D1.8B.D0.B5

Comment: Тут вопрос для чего вам это надо. Если для красоты, то кривые Безье подойдут. Если для фильтрации шумов, то надо использовать что-то другое, например скользящее среднее.

Comment: @dzhioev, что бы сгладит в числовом ряду "шум" и "пики" перед использованием его в расчетах.

Код "скользящего среднего":

    a=[40,40,40,40,37,40,36,39,36,39,34,39,35,38,33,37,35,34,36,35,34,33,33,33,32,33,32,33,32,33,31,32,29,31,29,31,28,33,27,30,25,29,24,28,28];
    for (var i=n, l=a.length; i<l; i++) {
     s=0; for (var j=i, m=i-n; j>=m; j--) s += a[j];
     r[i] = s/n;
    }

Код сглаживания Безье (квадратичная формула, 4-х кратный проход):

    for (var j=0, m=4; j<m; j++)
     for (var i=1, l=r.length-1; i<l; i++)
      r[i] = 0.5*(0.5*(r[i-1]+r[i+1])+r[i]);

Comment: @t1nk спасибо!

Comment: Вернулся к предложенному @sergiks метода "скользящей средней", в результате получил максимально близкое к желаемому.  
Так же смотрю в сторону [фильтра Калмана][1] (и [описание][2] подоступнее)

  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Фильтр_Калмана
  [2]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/140274/

Comment: Здравствуйте.
Попробуйте поискать здесь:
Дьяконов В. П. Справочник по алгоритмам и программам на языке бейсик для персональных ЭВМ. — М.: Наука, 1987. С. 240. Мне подошло нелинейное сглаживание по 7ми точкам.
С уважением Илья Л.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если это требуется только для графика — библиотека [D3js](http://d3js.org/) прекрасно справляется с этой задачей, даже можно динамически менять уровень сглаживания. Я недавно делал маленький проект, где как раз реализовал эту фишку ([пример](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3533396/d3jsexample/index.html)).

Если же интересует именно математика, то, возможно, подойдёт «[скользящее среднее](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%8F)» (simple moving average) из статистики: вместо значения в каждой точке, берите для графика среднее арифметическое от нее и N соседних точек ряда. Если провести параллель со звуком, вам нужно срезать верхние частоты, Low Pass фильтр : )

Comment: Интересует именно математика.  
Спасибо попробую "скользящее среднее".

Comment: @sergiks скорее всего и d3 умеет экспортировать точки.

Comment: Пока "скользящее среднее" + сглаживание Безье даёт результат наиболее близкий из опробованных способов к ручному наброску "гашения" пиков.  Осталось посмотреть что будет на реальных данных...

Comment: @t1nk было бы очень интересно увидеть код.

Comment: @lampa, код добавил в конец вопроса (если не будет лучшего варианта, то остановлюсь на нём).

Comment: @sergiks, после проверки на реальных данных расстроился - искажаются данные, кроме того число "точек" уменьшается на N и их приходится добавлять дополнительным небольшим проходом.  
  
PS  
Проведя дополнительные проверки на реальных данных уже с построением графиков, все таки согласился с вами, @sergiks, и своим первоначальным впечатлением от метода - наилучший результат получается от "скользящее среднее" + "сглаживание Безье".  
Ошибка была у меня в реализации метода - нужен был вариант для не линейной функции, иначе были грюки в местах "смены функций" (не помню как это правильно называется

Answer (score 5):

Короч смотри, что я тут придумал:

Берем http://mourner.github.io/simplify-js/ , т.е. урезаем твои 10 тыщ точек до 170.

Дальше я портанул из http://habrahabr.ru/post/130873/ библиотечку, сглаживающую шумы: https://github.com/lampaa/Bezier.js

А дальше как хочешь, можешь сглаживать, можешь нет, вот тут есть дельный коммент: http://www.gamedev.ru/code/forum/?id=124256&page=5#m64

Comment: Уменьшать количество точек вообще не вариант, но пройтись по ним в цикле вполне приемлемо.  
Спасибо за ссылки, обязательно попробую.

Comment: Ещё раз спасибо за алгоритм, но он ложится уже на том количестве значений что я использовал в тесте (см. код), а на длине ряда в несколько тысяч думаю и пытаться не стоит - факториалы убивают все напрочь...  
Для небольших графиков возможно и подойдет, но для моей задачи не подходит.

Answer (score 3):

а уменьшить количество точек нельзя?
Взять 5 диапазонов по три точки и каждый диапазон привести к средней
Может конечно я ошибаюсь

Comment: Если не получится обработать сразу весь рад значений, то так и сделаю.  
  
PS задача не геометрическая, нужно именно сгладить пики (в идеале убрать их) перед расчетами

Answer (score 2):

Обычно лучшее решение для нахождения тренда в реальных условиях - [медианное сглаживание в скользящем окне](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/479508/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9/479612#479612). Основания к его применению следующие:

1. Являясь непараметрическим методом, он не накладывает ограничений на модель тренда.
2. Метод не искажает монотонные последовательности данных и тем самым вносит минимальные искажения в выборку.
3. Метод сглаживает кратковременные колебания выборки.
4. Метод оптимален по отношению к кратковременным интенсивным выбросам данных.

Answer (score 0):

По идее, можно использовать метод наименьших квадратов со скользящим окном, т.е. на n-м количестве точек выборки, последовательно сдвигая их по выборке.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы.