# Как построить плавно возрастающий график?

Tags: c#, алгоритм, математика, геометрия

Хочу сгенерировать данные для построения графика следующего вида:

[image: График]

Область 1 и 3 я легко строю, а вот область 2 не могу правильно построить. Мой алгоритм построения участка 2 сводится к следующему:

> зная уравнение прямой `y = ax + b` я плавно изменяю коэффициент `a` от
> 0 до нужного мне значения, соответствующего заданному углу наклона
> прямой (участок 3).

Получился такой метод:

```
private static void FillAsRiseLine(double[] data, int from, int to, double fromA, double toA, double deviation)
{
    var a = fromA;
    var stepA = (toA - fromA) / (to - from);

    for (var x = from; x <= to; x++)
    {
        var b = data[from] - a * from;
        data[x] = x * a + GetRandDouble(b - deviation, b + deviation);
        a += stepA;
    }
}
```

Все вроде бы хорошо, но график выглядит не так, как хотелось. Ниже выводится полученный результат (красный пунктир - это для наглядности добавил):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно, наклон кривой участка №2 стал слишком большим. И теперь я в тупике и ищу помощи тех, кто хорошо разбирается в геометрии. Как можно построить участок №2 таким образом, чтобы кривая на выходе имела угол наклона равный углу наклон прямой участка №3?

**UPD.** Суть вопроса в следующем: как, зная:

1. точку начала кривой *(x1, y1)*
2. значение производной в точке *(x1, y1) = 0*
3. координату *x2* точки, где кривая должна заканчиваться
4. значение производной кривой в точке *x2*

построить плавно возрастающую кривую?

Comment: Так, как у вас изображено - ничего не получится. Надо отступить левее. Но в общем случае можно построить кривую, требуя не только совпадения точек сочленения, но и производных в этих точках.

Comment: `я плавно изменяю коэффициент a` почему только `a`? что насчет `b`?

Comment: @Harry что вы имеете ввиду, говоря "отступить левее"?

Comment: @tym32167 коэффициент `b` я тоже менял (в функции на каждой итерации он пересчитывался). Я решал эту задачу на интуитивном уровне. Просто понимал, что нужно плавно изменять производную, чтобы функция росла. Но вот сам метод построения кривой не дает мне правильно построить кривую, потому что коэффициент `a` уже не является производной в этом случае.

Comment: @Harry обновил вопрос, пояснив суть задачи, которую я не могу решить.

Comment: В приведённом внизу примере нельзя построить плавное монотонное сочленение - для этого продолжение наклонной должно пересекать нижнюю прямую правее её конца (или нижняя должна заканчиваться раньше, как Harry сказал). S-образное сочленение можно построить, но будет ли это в данном случае подходяще?

Comment: Строите виртуально треугольник, одна сторона которого - это соединяющая 2 точки линия, 2 других стороны - перпендикуляры к касательным графика в данных точках, пересечение этих перпендикуляров - вершина треугольника. Дальше по эти трем точкам можно построить эллипс, секция эллипса между двумя исходными точками и есть требуемый кусок графика, но это частный случай, можно дальше эту идею додумать.

Comment: [Вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/323753/%D0%90%D0%BF%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%88%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%83) еще что нашел.

Answer (score 2):

Нужно вписать часть окружности в угол образованный из двух прямых так чтобы эти прямые оказались касательными к окружности. Тогда и будет у вас будет плавный переход.

Обновлено.
Можно также использовать кривые
[Безье](https://learn.javascript.ru/bezier-curve)

Comment: Увы, в общем случае это не всегда возможно...

Comment: Да в случае если между касательными нет второй зоны

Comment: Я вот что имею в виду - у такой окружности, раз она касательная к обеим точкам разрыва, центр должен лежать на перпендикулярах к точкам, в точке их пересечения. Но при этом совершенно не обязательно должно быть совпадение расстояний от точек пересечения нормалей до точек разрывов - т.е. радиусы получаются разные. С точки зрения алгебраической - есть 4 переменные - координаты и производные, но у окружности нет такого количества параметров...

Answer (score 2):

Если из самого условия не следует что-то получше, можно воспользоваться кубическим полиномом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее мы просто подставляем значения переменных и получаем

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее просто решаем эту систему уравнений - численно, или аналитически - например, с помощью Wolfram Mathematica

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(простите уж, переводить в красивые формулы не стану... думаю, вы и сами сможете перевести, если нужно будет), а потом по этой формуле просчитать с тем шагом x, который вам нужен, значения y...

Comment: Осталось дописать, что это сплайн интерполяция.

Comment: Объемная формула вышла, однако. Эх, ладно. У меня получилось решить эту задачу своим методом. Я чуть позже выложу ответ об этом. Не думал, что задача имеет такое непростое решение